# How to write Kafka Producer in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I need help in publishing a message to a topic using kafka producer.
My kafka producer client is written in scala running over spark.

My Job runs successfully but it seems my message is not published.

Here is the code

```
val response = info.producer.asInstanceOf[KafkaProducer[K, V]].send(new ProducerRecord(info.props.getProperty(s"$topicNickName.topic"), keyMessage._1, keyMessage._2))
```

Producer Config Values

```
metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    bootstrap.servers = [x.data.edh:6667, y.data.edh:6667, z.data.edh:6667, a.data.edh:6667, b.data.edh:6667]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    max.block.ms = 60000
    interceptor.classes = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = 
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    acks = 1
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    retries = 0
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    compression.type = none
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    timeout.ms = 30000
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    ssl.key.password = null
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    batch.size = 16384
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    max.request.size = 1048576
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    linger.ms = 0
```

How do i debug the problem?

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of how to produce messages to Kafka in Scala:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

val kafkaProducerProps: Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "x.data.edh:6667")
    props.put("key.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer].getName)
    props.put("value.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer].getName)
    props
  }

val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](kafkaProducerProps)
producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String]("myTopic", keyMessage._1, keyMessage._2))
```

If you want to do streaming I recommend to have a look at the [Spark + Kafka integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html).

Note that the example given above is a KafkaProducer in a *fire-and-forget* mode. There are the following modes on how to use Kafka Producer:

> **Fire-and-forget**
>   We send a message to the server and don’t really care if it arrives succesfully or not. Most of the time, it will arrive successfully, since Kafka is highly available and the producer will retry sending messages automatically. However, some messages will get lost using this method.
>
> **Synchronous send**
>   We send a message, the `send()` method returns a Future object, and we use `get()` to wait on the future and see if the `send()` was successful or not.
>
> **Asynchronous send**
>   We call the `send()` method with a `callback` function, which gets triggered when it receives a response from the Kafka broker

#### Synchronous Example

```scala
producer.send(record).get()
```

#### Asynchronous Example

```scala
producer.send(record, new compareProducerCallback)
producer.flush()

// Callback trait only contains the one abstract method onCompletion
private class compareProducerCallback extends Callback {
  @Override
  override def onCompletion(metadata: RecordMetadata, exception: Exception): Unit = {
    if (exception != null) {
      exception.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}
```